# Running YOLOv8 on openVINO runtime

Tags: python, computer-vision, yolo, openvino

I trained a detection model using yolov8n.pt base which was recommended. But it very slow, inference takes way too long it renders the project impractical but I understand on a good GPU like nvidia it will be way faster but my system makes use of intel CPU. Making the openvino runtime by intel an option for optimisation.
I convert the 'onnx' model to IR files using the openvino mo command and proceed to load the weights to run on the openvino runtime.

## My problem

The output shape seems irregular and I have tried manipulating and looking through the yolov8n.yaml file and comapre it to the IR files to understand the output. But i can't get any sort of meaning.
I tried using yolov8s.pt and a different dataset but the output shape after Openvino optimisation remains the same

input shape : [1,3,640,640]

output shape: [1,6,8400]

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from openvino.runtime import Core
from ultralytics import YOLO
ie = Core()

model = ie.read_model(model=r"\models\IR\model_fit.xml")
compiled_model = ie.compile_model(model=model, device_name="CPU")

input_layer_ir = compiled_model.input(0)
output_layer_ir = compiled_model.output()


image = cv2.imread(r'\Resources\test_image.jpg')
N, C, H, W = input_layer_ir.shape
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (W, H))
input_image = np.expand_dims(resized_image.transpose(2, 0, 1), 0)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB));
boxes = compiled_model([input_image])[output_layer_ir]

print(boxes.shape)
```

```
<Output: names[output0] shape[1,6,8400] type: f32>
```

Has anyone experienced this and how do I go about this to get my box co-ordinates for detection?
Or can some computer-vision expert attempt this ? Note I am a beginner to computer-vision

Comment: Any chance you could share your ONNX model? BTW, you can feed the ONNX model directly to OV runtime, there's no need to convert it to IR using MO.

Comment: @tomdol Yes I have tried, but the output shape still remains the same.

Comment: I could have a look but it would help a lot if you shared your ONNX model to make sure we're looking at the same topology.

Comment: @tomdol here is a link to [onnx file](https://wormhole.app/p1AP3#BvlajeerDLhVpf4425Wz6A)

Comment: I've investigated the shared ONNX model and tried exporting it myself according to the Ultralytics docs. In any case the resulting model contains a single output with 3 dimensions which is a bit unusual comparing to the previous versions of the Yolo model family. When you run the model created using the ultralytics module in python you get an object containing 3 fields: boxes, masks and probs. The boxes field should contain the detections from the input image and the shape of this tensor is Nx6 where N indicates the number of detected items. The export of the model might not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it shows that the output shape is fixed, which is not your expection, right?

I think you can check the conversion from PyTorch to ONNX. In this phase, you should keep the shape dynamic instead of static.

If possible, maybe you can share the original pytorch model.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I have stumbled upon this problem too, I believe from the output shape [1,6,8400] you are seeing you can take the first value and transpose to [8400, 6] giving you 8400 rows of the format [x, y, width, height, probability class 0, probability class 1], assuming you have 2 classes.

Also, depending on what you are running on you may need to use cv2.dnn.blobFromImage instead of np.expand_dims, I've added this in the snippet so you can try as well.

So to process the code would look like:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import numpy as np
from openvino.runtime import Core

ie = Core()

model = ie.read_model(model=r"\models\IR\model_fit.xml")
compiled_model = ie.compile_model(model=model, device_name="CPU")

input_layer_ir = compiled_model.input(0)
output_layer_ir = compiled_model.output()

image = cv2.imread(r'\Resources\test_image.jpg')
N, C, H, W = input_layer_ir.shape
# resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (W, H))
# input_image = np.expand_dims(resized_image.transpose(2, 0, 1), 0)
input_image = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image , 1/255, (W, H), [0,0,0], 1, crop=False)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB));
output = compiled_model([input_image])[output_layer_ir]

output = cv2.transpose(output[0])
print("Response shape", output.shape)

boxes = []
scores = []
class_ids = []

for row in output:
    # Each row is [x, y, width, height, probability class 0, probability class 1, ...]
    classes_scores = row[4:]
    (_min_score, max_score, _min_class_loc, (_x, max_class_index)) = cv2.minMaxLoc(classes_scores)
    if max_score >= 0.25:
        box = [row[0] - (0.5 * row[2]), row[1] - (0.5 * row[3]), row[2], row[3]]
        boxes.append(box)
        scores.append(max_score)
        class_ids.append(max_class_index)

[height, width, _] = image.shape
length = max((height, width))
scale = length/480

# Apply NMS (Non-maximum suppression)
RESULT_BOXES = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, scores, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5)
for index in RESULT_BOXES:
    box = boxes[index]
    x, y = round(box[0] * scale), round(box[1] * scale)
    x_plus_w, y_plus_h = round((box[0] + box[2]) * scale), round((box[1] + box[3]) * scale)
    draw_image = cv2.rectangle(cv2.UMat(image), (x, y), (x_plus_w, y_plus_h), (0, 0, 255), 4)

cv2.imwrite(r'\Resources\test_image_result.jpg', image)
```

There is more detail here: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/examples/YOLOv8-OpenCV-ONNX-Python/main.py

Hope that helps, and if so could you let me know how you exported your model from YoloV8? I have done it but it gives me weird results using the IE Core instead of loading and running with YOLO